# How would I use GLM for Bullet Physics?

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d-meshes, blender, bullet-physics

Right now im working on my c++ game, and im having alot of trouble using [GLM](http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/Working-with-3D-models/Getting-GLM.html) and Bullet Physics to create my world correctly.

The main problem is that when i export my physics with [Blender](http://blender.org)v2.57, and export my models for GLM, the models never line up with the physics correctly...

Im wondering if there are any model loaders that would be good to use with Bullet Physics, and I can export the vertices,texture coords, etc. from Blender to be loaded and used as btTriangleMeshes..

I managed to make a `btBvhTriangleMesh` with my GLM model, but I think its falling, or my character is not picking it up correctly..

heres the code:

```
void BulletifyContinent(GLMmodel* mesh,float x,float y,float z,float scale)
{
    btTriangleMesh* trimesh = new btTriangleMesh();
    for(int t=0;t<mesh->numtriangles;++t)
    {
        GLuint index0 =3*mesh->triangles[t].vindices[0];
        GLuint index1 =3*mesh->triangles[t].vindices[1];
        GLuint index2 =3*mesh->triangles[t].vindices[2];

        GLfloat* p0 = &mesh->vertices[index0];
        GLfloat* p1 = &mesh->vertices[index1];
        GLfloat* p2 = &mesh->vertices[index2];

        btVector3* v0 = new btVector3( p0[0], p0[1], p0[2] );
        btVector3* v1 = new btVector3( p1[0], p1[1], p1[2] );
        btVector3* v2 = new btVector3( p2[0], p2[1], p2[2] );
        *v0 *= scale;
        *v1 *= scale;
        *v2 *= scale;
        trimesh->addTriangle( *v0, *v1, *v2 );
        ///trimesh->addTriangle(mesh->triangles[t].vindices[0]*100,mesh->triangles[t].vindices[1]*100,mesh->triangles[t].vindices[2]*100);
    }
    btCollisionShape* shape = 0;
    bool useQuantization = true;
    shape = new btBvhTriangleMeshShape(trimesh,useQuantization);
    btDefaultMotionState *StillStateMOT = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,0),btVector3(x,y,z)));
    btScalar Mass = 1;
    btVector3 FallInertia(0,0,0);
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo StillRigidCI(Mass,StillStateMOT,shape,FallInertia);
    btRigidBody *ContiRigid = new btRigidBody(StillRigidCI);
    PhysicsWorld->addRigidBody(ContiRigid);
```

Edit 1:

```
btScalar Mass = 1;
btVector3 FallInertia(0,0,0);
// This line is missing in your code
shape->calculateLocalInertia(Mass, FallInertia);
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo StillRigidCI(Mass,StillStateMOT,shape,FallInertia);
btRigidBody *ContiRigid = new btRigidBody(StillRigidCI);
PhysicsWorld->addRigidBody(ContiRigid);
```

Edit 2:

There is no need to create the bullet vertices on the heap with new:

```
btVector3 v0( p0[0], p0[1], p0[2] );
btVector3 v1( p1[0], p1[1], p1[2] );
btVector3 v2( p2[0], p2[1], p2[2] );
v0 *= scale;
v1 *= scale;
v2 *= scale;
trimesh->addTriangle( v0, v1, v2 );
```

Edit 3:

This is not a proper identity quaternion:

```
btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,0),btVector3(x,y,z)));
```

either do it this way:

```
btTransform trans;
trans.setIdentity();
trans.setOrigin(btVector3(x,y,z));
btDefaultMotionState *StillStateMOT = new btDefaultMotionState(trans);
```

or by passing a proper identity quaternion either yourself:

```
btDefaultMotionState *StillStateMOT = 
    new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1),btVector3(x,y,z)));
```

or using quaternion's identity member function:

```
btDefaultMotionState *StillStateMOT = 
    new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion::getIdentity(),btVector3(x,y,z)));
```

Comment: You forgot to calculate the local inertia for the shape, add `shape->calculateLocalInertia(Mass, FallInertia);` in the line after `btVector3 FallInertia(0,0,0);`

Comment: You don't need to create the triangle vertices on the heap with new, look for my edit in your question

Comment: I added the corrected code to your question, see Edit 1 and Edit 2 If you have further questions regarding this code, start a new question with the code examples.

Comment: There was an invalid quaternion passed to the initial body transform. Added Edit 3.

Comment: In the future please start new questions with the code details if new questions arise, it doesn't cost you anything and makes your question history more readable. Your new question was down voted because you simply repeated the old question instead of starting a new one with the new information i.e. the above code samples. Just don't repeat the old question, provide all necessary information in the new question and leave the old one as it was.

Comment: @Molmasepic triggering notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a good model loader for Bullet Physics?

Bullet has a build-in model/world-loader. Export everything in blender to `.bullet` and simply load it using `btBulletWorldImporter`

[Here is a wiki explaining the details](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Bullet_binary_serialization#Loading_a_.bullet_file.2C_creating_objects_and_adding_them_to_the_world)

Comment: I wish everything were this simple :D

Comment: i know it has a world importer, Im doing this right now. But the problem is that Im using GLm to load my models...And when doing so, the models that are textured do not line up with the collision meshes that the .bullet file provides..

Comment: Did you compare both data after loading? Use a debugger and compare certain vertices. Other than that it's hard to tell whats wrong. Could be everything. Use the debugger.

Comment: the main way i compared the data is checking if my player is exactly on the spot in the GLM model when colliding with the physics world. And i have multiple "areas" that were put in this physics file...Im wondering if maybe theres a way to use the vertices from the GLM loaded model for the bullet physics mesh. I have attempted this before and it caused the game to crash...i wondering how to do it right..

Comment: Yes you can use the vertices from GLM. You have to use a [btBvhTriangleMeshShape](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtBvhTriangleMeshShape.html) and pass this as colision shape when creating the rigid body. You will find some examples when you search in the bullet demos for `btBvhTriangleMeshShape`. I'll edit my answer and add the example usage from a demo

Comment: Here is how you can add the vertices on your own to a bullet-mesh: You can either use [btTriangleMesh](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTriangleMesh.html) or [btTriangleIndexVertexArray](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTriangleIndexVertexArray.html), add the triangles to them, their usage is pretty straight forward. Then create a [btBvhTriangleMeshShape](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtBvhTriangleMeshShape.html) using the triangle-mesh as constructor parameter, then create the rigid body with it

Comment: You will find some examples in the Bullet Demos, just search for those classes.

Comment: Please check my new answer concerning: `models that are textured do not line up with the collision meshes that the .bullet file provides`

Answer (score 0):

> And when doing so, the models that are textured do not line up with the collision meshes that the .bullet file provides

How much off are they? Bullet adds a little margin to the boundaries of each body depending of the collision shape, that's ok and pretty small (~0.04) This is what the [Docs](http://www.bulletphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/physics/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf) say:

**Collision Margin**

*Bullet uses a small collision margin for collision shapes, to improve performance and reliability of the collision detection. It is best not to modify the default collision margin, and if you do use a positive value: zero margin might introduce problems. By default this collision margin is set to 0.04, which is 4 centimeter if your units are in meters (recommended).*

*Dependent on which collision shapes, the margin has different meaning. Generally the collision margin will expand the object. This will create a small gap. To compensate for this, some shapes will subtract the margin from the actual size. For example, the btBoxShape subtracts the collision margin from the half extents. For a btSphereShape, the entire radius is collision margin so no gap will occur. Don’t override the collision margin for spheres. For convex hulls, cylinders and cones, the margin is added to the extents of the object, so a gap will occur, unless you adjust the graphics mesh or collision size. For convex hull objects, there is a method to remove the gap introduced by the margin, by shrinking the object. See the Demos/BspDemo for this advanced use*

Comment: theyre not off all the same..some of the models could be 2-3 units off, while other models could be exactly on point..im going to attempt the btTriangleMesh again, but im not sure how it will work since i moved the graphics model to another spot(translate) and i also scaled most of the models

Comment: You can't scale rigid bodies with bullet. What do you mean you scaled them?

Comment: It sounds more like the rendering is wrong. Like i.e. wrong matrix multiplication order.

Comment: hey i managed to get the mesh to transfer to a `btBvhTriangleMesh`, but i think its falling...Im going to edit my question to show the code i used to create the rigid body

Comment: Take your time, debug the issue, then write a new question with the new information.

Comment: oh i didnt mean i scaled the rigid body, i meant that i scaled the rednering model to make it bigger

Comment: how would I go about debugging info? all i know is how to stop the errors...

Comment: Well, if you scaled the rendering model, then of course the bullet mesh is off! What did you expect?

Comment: i had no choice! everytime i go to export my .obj file, it scales the mesh down until its in a 1 unit radius

Comment: I would fix that in the first place, otherwise you will have a chain of ugly hacks and lots of pain, as you already see.

Comment: then maybe i should find another model loader to use? any suggestions??

Comment: But you were not talking about the loader, you said `everytime i go to export my .obj file, it scales the mesh down`. So the problem is the export, not the loader.

Comment: hm..true...maybe theres a setting that i can use...or better yet i can check out the .obj file

Comment: i think that by looking at the code that i provided, i may be missing something important that includes the collision or something..could you just help check if everythings there?